# How to get the certificate details exchanged between server & client if it's activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Like in socket where we have a method addHandshakeCompletedListener() which would allow us to generate specific details once handshake between two parties are successful , if the communication is activemq and it SSL enabled how to retrieve the certificate details on handshake complete , like expriy details

Answer (score 0):

From the documentations (haven't tried it myself):

From your activemq connection object:
http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnection.html

- Call .getTransport();

With the transport Object returned:
http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/Transport.html

- Call .getPeerCertificates()

This should return the list of peer certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , but do we have api to retrieve localCertificates that been shared during the transportation or handshake ? like in socket where it exposes both localCertificates & peerCertificates during the handshake , do we have in activemq ?